# Plotting exponential function python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I get a linear graph when trying to plot exponential function:

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def graph(formula, x_range):
   x = np.array(x_range)
   y = eval(formula)
   plt.plot(x, y)

graph('100*(np.power(0.8, x))', (0,100))
```

what am I doing wrong?
[output_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HEecP.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You really should NOT BE USING EVAL. However, leaving that issue aside, the problem is you are passing a tuple of two values as the argument for the x_range parameter. This is creating a `x` with the value: `array([  0, 100])`, and if you create the corresponding y's, you'll only have two points so of course you'll get a line. You want to use `np.arange` instead of `np.array`. However, if you pass a tuple to your `graph` function you are going to need to unpack the tuple when you pass it to `np.arange.` So this should work:

```
def graph(formula, x_range):
   x = np.arange(*x_range)
   y = eval(formula)
   plt.plot(x, y)
```

Seriously, though, instead of `eval` why not just pass a function?

```
def graph(func, x_range):
   x = np.arange(*x_range)
   y = func(x)
   plt.plot(x, y)

graph(lambda x: 100*(np.power(0.8, x)), (0,100))
```

Results:

[image]

Comment: @PrinceP No worries, but please check out my edit regarding using `eval`

Comment: @juanpa-arrivillaga Thank you once again. I'm new to python, I like your code.